# Вычисление Load Average для Windows

Tags: java, windows, cpu

Как можно вычислить Load Average системы с ОС Windows?
(Язык программирования - java).
Sigar API и OperatingSystemMXBean не вычисляют Load Average под Windows.

Comment: в винде нет такого понятия. Можно конечно попробовать вычислить, но смысл? Какую задачу Вы решаете?

Comment: мониторинг серверов (Windows Server 2003)

Answer (score 1):

Самое близкое к `load average` понятие в Windows это `Process Queue Length`.

> Количество процессов, отмеченных как «отложенные» в очереди готовности
>   процессора и ожидающих назначения на выполнение. Потоки выполнения в
>   очереди готовности процессора размещены по приоритетности: поток с
>   наивысшим приоритетом будет запущен следующим, как только процессор
>   будет свободен.

Добыть его можно из WMI с помощью [Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_System](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394272(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать.